# Vue Router view not working in laravel blade page

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I am new in vue js. I have tried to run ExampleComponent.vue and it run ok in my admin panel showing its content. Now I want to import routes from external file (new_route_list.js) and load it via AdminMaster.vue router-view.   But now the problem is that  in admin panel it not working with . Nothing shown when I hit in 'project-name/home'. But It should load AdminHome.vue content.

Also, npm run watch & browser's vue js console showing no error.

Please help me to figure out where is the problem.

In app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

import {v_routes} from './new_route_list.js';

Vue.component('admin-main', require('./components/admin/AdminMaster.vue'));

const router = new VueRouter({
  v_routes, 
   mode:'history'
})

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
  router
});
```

AdminHome.vue

```
<template>
<div>
    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h3 class="card-title">Title</h3>

                <div class="card-tools">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-tool" data-widget="collapse" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Collapse">
                        <i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-tool" data-widget="remove" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Remove">
                        <i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                Start creating your amazing application .....!
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                Footer
            </div>
            <!-- /.card-footer-->
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- /.content -->
</div>
```

AdminMaster.vue

```
<template>
<div id="adminmain">
    <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

new_route_list.js

```
import AdminHome from './components/admin/AdminHome.vue'
export const v_routes = [
{
    path:'/home',
    component: AdminHome
}
]
```

In admin_master.blade.php I have added:

```
    <div class="wrapper" id="app">
  <!-- Navbar -->
  <nav class="main-header navbar navbar-expand navbar-white navbar-light">
    <!-- Left navbar links -->

    <!-- Right navbar links -->
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <!-- Messages Dropdown Menu -->
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
          <i class="far fa-comments"></i>
          <span class="badge badge-danger navbar-badge">3</span>
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-lg dropdown-menu-right">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
            <!-- Message Start -->
            <div class="media">
              <img src="{{ asset('assets/admin/default/admin.png')}}" alt="User Avatar" class="img-size-50 mr-3 img-circle">
              <div class="media-body">
                <h3 class="dropdown-item-title">
                  Brad Diesel
                  <span class="float-right text-sm text-danger"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></span>
                </h3>
                <p class="text-sm">Call me whenever you can...</p>
                <p class="text-sm text-muted"><i class="far fa-clock mr-1"></i> 4 Hours Ago</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Message End -->
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
            <!-- Message Start -->
            <div class="media">
              <img src="{{ asset('assets/admin/default/admin.png')}}" alt="User Avatar" class="img-size-50 img-circle mr-3">
              <div class="media-body">
                <h3 class="dropdown-item-title">
                  John Pierce
                  <span class="float-right text-sm text-muted"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></span>
                </h3>
                <p class="text-sm">I got your message bro</p>
                <p class="text-sm text-muted"><i class="far fa-clock mr-1"></i> 4 Hours Ago</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Message End -->
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
            <!-- Message Start -->
            <div class="media">
              <img src="{{ asset('assets/admin/default/admin.png')}}" alt="User Avatar" class="img-size-50 img-circle mr-3">
              <div class="media-body">
                <h3 class="dropdown-item-title">
                  Nora Silvester
                  <span class="float-right text-sm text-warning"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></span>
                </h3>
                <p class="text-sm">The subject goes here</p>
                <p class="text-sm text-muted"><i class="far fa-clock mr-1"></i> 4 Hours Ago</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Message End -->
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-item dropdown-footer">See All Messages</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <!-- Notifications Dropdown Menu -->
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
          <i class="far fa-bell"></i>
          <span class="badge badge-warning navbar-badge">15</span>
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-lg dropdown-menu-right">
          <span class="dropdown-item dropdown-header">15 Notifications</span>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
            <i class="fas fa-envelope mr-2"></i> 4 new messages
            <span class="float-right text-muted text-sm">3 mins</span>
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>

          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-item dropdown-footer">See All Notifications</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-widget="control-sidebar" data-slide="true" href="#">
          <i class="fas fa-th-large"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <!-- /.navbar -->

  <!-- Main Sidebar Container -->
  <aside class="main-sidebar sidebar-dark-primary elevation-4">
    <!-- Brand Logo -->
    <a href="../../index3.html" class="brand-link">
      <img src="{{ asset('assets/admin/default/AdminLTELogo.png')}}"
           alt="AdminLTE Logo"
           class="brand-image img-circle elevation-3"
           style="opacity: .8">
      <span class="brand-text font-weight-light">Admin Panel</span>
    </a>

    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div class="sidebar">
      <!-- Sidebar user (optional) -->
      <div class="user-panel mt-3 pb-3 mb-3 d-flex">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="{{ asset('assets/admin/default/admin.png')}}" class="img-circle elevation-2" alt="User Image">
        </div>
        <div class="info">
          <a href="#" class="d-block">{{Auth::user()->name}}</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Sidebar Menu -->
      <nav class="mt-2">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-sidebar flex-column" data-widget="treeview" role="menu" data-accordion="false">
          <!-- Add icons to the links using the .nav-icon class
               with font-awesome or any other icon font library -->
          <li class="nav-item has-treeview">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">
              <i class="nav-icon fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
              <p>
                Dashboard
                <i class="right fas fa-angle-left"></i>
              </p>
            </a>

          </li>

           <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="../widgets.html" class="nav-link">
              <i class="nav-icon fas fa-th"></i>
              <p>
                Posts
                <span class="right badge badge-danger">New</span>
              </p>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item has-treeview">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">
              <i class="nav-icon fas fa-copy"></i>
              <p>
                Layout Options
                <i class="fas fa-angle-left right"></i>
                <span class="badge badge-info right">6</span>
              </p>
            </a>
            <ul class="nav nav-treeview">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="../layout/top-nav.html" class="nav-link">
                  <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>
                  <p>Top Navigation</p>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="../layout/collapsed-sidebar.html" class="nav-link">
                  <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>
                  <p>Collapsed Sidebar</p>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>


        </ul>
      </nav>
      <!-- /.sidebar-menu -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.sidebar -->
  </aside>

  <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <section class="content-header">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row mb-2">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h1>Admin Home Page</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </section>

    <!-- Main content -->
    <admin-main></admin-main>
    <!-- /.content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.content-wrapper -->


  <!-- Control Sidebar -->
  <aside class="control-sidebar control-sidebar-dark">
    <!-- Control sidebar content goes here -->
  </aside>
  <!-- /.control-sidebar -->
</div>
```

Comment: I have added blade file code. Yes, I have added #app in div.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it wasn't working is because of the way the `const` was named in the `new_route_list.js` file. You have to name it `routes` since it is short for

```
new VueRouter({
    routes: [
        ///routes here
    ],
    mode:'history'
});
```

This is shown in this example here:

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#javascript

Another thing I noticed was the `AdminMaster.vue` file. It feels redundant, so I would recommend removing it and just do this in your `admin_master.blade.php`:

```
<!-- Main content -->
    <router-view></router-view>
<!-- /.content -->
```

---

Edit: Your files will need to be updated for this change

Here is `app.js`:

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import { routes } from './new_route_list.js'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes,
    mode:'history'
});

const app = new Vue({
    router
}).$mount("#app");
```

I updated the `new Vue()` with `.$mount()` and removed `el:'#app'` per the the example shown in the link above.

Here is the update to `new_route_list.js`:

```
import adminHome from './AdminHome.vue';

export const routes = [
    {
        path:'/',
        component: adminHome
    }
]
```

Update `AdminHome.vue` too. You need to wrap the template in the closing `</template>` tag and then you need to have script tags that export the component like shown below:

```
<template>
<div>
    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h3 class="card-title">Title</h3>

                <div class="card-tools">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-tool" data-widget="collapse" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Collapse">
                        <i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-tool" data-widget="remove" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Remove">
                        <i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                Start creating your amazing application .....!
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                Footer
            </div>
            <!-- /.card-footer-->
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- /.content -->
</div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: as I am importing  {v_routes} from new_route_list.js, export name should be v_routes. If i change it I am getting error in npm run watch

Comment: changed according to your code. npm watch showing no error but component not showing under router-view